# Sails 0.10 & Many-to-Many association - Get all associated data, not the first only

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have 2 models with a Many-to-Many association. My code to associate these two models is working well (it create a new collection `item_languages__language_items` with the corresponding documents inside). But then I have trouble to get all the associated data (languages) of a specific item. I'm using MongoDB.

```
// Item.js
module.exports = {
    schema: true,
    autoPK: false,
    attributes: {
        uuid: {
            type: 'string',
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true,
            required: true,
            uuidv4: true
        },
        languages: {
            collection: 'language',
            via: 'items',
            dominant: true
        }
    }
}

// Language.js
module.exports = {
    schema: true,
    autoPK: false,
    attributes: {
        code: {
            type: 'string',
            primaryKey: true,
            required: true,
            minLength: 2,
            maxLength: 2,
            unique: true
        },
        items: {
            collection: 'item',
            via: 'languages'
        }
    }
}
```

Data stored in the `item_languages__language_items` collection:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "language_items" : "es",
    "item_languages" : "69e4f3a3-1247-4a06-ae2d-9df27ac9495b",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5330bcebf8e0b61509c771d5")
}

/* 1 */
{
    "language_items" : "fr",
    "item_languages" : "69e4f3a3-1247-4a06-ae2d-9df27ac9495b",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5330bd26f8e0b61509c771d6")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "language_items" : "en",
    "item_languages" : "69e4f3a3-1247-4a06-ae2d-9df27ac9495b",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5330bedcc076355b09da3ccd")
}
```

Now in my `ItemController.js`, I want to get a specific item with all associated languages:

```
Item
    .findOne({uuid: '69e4f3a3-1247-4a06-ae2d-9df27ac9495b'})
    .populate('languages')
    .exec(function (e, r) {
        console.log(r.toJSON());
    });
```

But here I get my item with only 1 associated language, when I expected to get the 3 associated languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the current beta implementation of `sails-mongo` which keeps `populate` from working properly with custom-defined keys.  Please [post this to the sails-mongo issues forum](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues?page=1&state=open)!  In the meantime the only solution appears to be to use the default MongoDB primary keys.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have posted an issue here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/120. In the meantime I will use a workaround.

Comment: Fixed in the latest Waterline with the commit mentioned here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/120